# Edited volumes in bibliography: (eds) or (eds.)?

Tags: citations

I was recently informed that (eds) **NOT** (eds.) was the 'correct' way (i.e not simply down to journal style guidelines) to describe volumes with multiple editors. Conversely, according to this same source, (ed.) should be used rather than (ed). Surely both (ed.) and (eds.) are abbreviations and therefore both require the full stop to indicate this?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic here, as it's about the English language. Anyway, I believe the answer is that you put a dot to indicate a *truncation*, such as "**prof**essor => Prof." or "**ed**itor => ed.", but not for an *abbreviation* such as "**d**octo**r** => Dr", "Mister => Mr", "Mistress => Mrs" or "**ed**itor**s** => eds". But this differs between the USA and the UK, what I just described is for the UK. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-abbreviations

Comment: My old Collins dictionary agrees with you. My old AIP Style Manual also agrees with you. How would your informant deal with Fig. vs Figs. or Eq. vs Eqs. for example (both a 'standard abbreviation' per AIP)?

Comment: Hmmm. "Informed" by whom? Consider the source. If it is someone with authority over the publication, yield. Don't try to overrule an editor, for example.

Comment: In this case I am the copyeditor and the source is the author. I don't really mind who overrules who but want our house guidelines to be 'correct' (if that applies in this case). Now I'm erring towards agreeing with them after reading the Oxford dictionary link above.

Comment: I suppose under these rules 'Figures' would simply abbreviate to 'Figs' though that seems a little awkward.

Comment: I would go through several standard journals in your field and see how they deal with the question. Consult their style manuals.

Comment: @Beeman "Figs 2-4 show three variants of figs."

Comment: @Anyon—exactly!—what is this madness?

Answer (score 3):

[APA 6th edition](https://bowvalleycollege.libguides.com/c.php?g=494959&p=3386832) uses "Eds." So there's at least one reputed style guide that abbreviates in the plural with a fullstop.